# Docking station for USB video recorders

Tags: usb, docking-stations, video-editing

I need to connect several USB video capture devices to my laptop but its USB ports have the internal bus shared, which means that, although it recognizes all the independent capture devices, I can only get video signal from the first one I connect as it doesn't support the load from the others. I am looking for a docking station, which would be connected to only one of those ports on my laptop. Would it work? Does a high end docking station handle the data stream directly or would it be like using a cheap USB hub?

Comment: What 'flavour' of USB? I doubt USB2 could handle it, but USB-C/Thunderbolt likely could.

Comment: I was thinking more like USB3. Unfortunately C and others are out of my range.

Comment: "more like USB3" ?? It can only be what your mobo's USB capability is, which is what I was asking. You don't get to choose, nor can you connect a hub with higher capability than the socket you plug it into.

Comment: Yes, I meant that my motherboard has usb3 ports.